# Blender 2.82 Light go through mesh after applying volumetric

Tags: rendering, eevee-render-engine

[image]

I am not sure wha is causing this problem, please tell me what you think! Thanks.

Comment: Does this also happen when looking through the camera or being in perspective mode?

Comment: Hello :). I remember some other posts regarding the same issue. You can try searching this site, perhaps it has a solution. (or maybe it's a bug)

Comment: Sry I didn’t find the answer on this site, It will still occurs when I look through camera

Comment: Volumétrica un revés are quite limited, if the light is not in visible fo camera the effect doesn't work